# On the preclusion number of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

A set of edges in a graph $G$ is a matching if no two of the edges have a vertex in common. For an even integer $n$, an $n$-vertex graph $G$ has a perfect matching if there are $\frac{n}{2}$ edges $x_1 y_1 ,x_2 y_2, \ldots ,x_{\frac{n}{2}}y_{\frac{n}{2}}$ involving all of the vertices of $G$. If $n$ is odd, $G$ has an odd-perfect matching if there are $\frac{(n-1)}{2}$ such edges involving all but one the vertices of $G$. A set $F$ of edges of $G$ is called a preclusion set if $G-F$ has no perfect and odd-perfect matching. The matching preclusion number of $G$, $mp(G)$, is the size of a minimum preclusion set.

My question is that:

If $G$ a graph with even order $n$, then why $mp(G)\leq \delta(G)$?

What I tried: Let $v$ be a vertex with $\deg (v)=\delta(G)$. Let $F$ be the set of all edges incident with vertex $v$. I want to show that $G-F$ has no perfect (or odd-perfect matching). If $G-F$ has a matching, then $v(G-F)=even$ hence $v(G)=odd$ which is a contradiction. But I don't know how to show $G-F$ hos no odd-perfect matching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 interesting question, nicely presented, reasonable work shown - and I *loathe* graph theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when $n$ is even, we need to take $F$ the set of all edges incident with vertex $v$. Then there is no edge in $G-F$ incident to $v$ hence there is no perfect matching. Therefore $mp(G)\leq \delta(G)$. But when $n$ is odd, that's not the case at all because by the definition of $F$, $G-F$ can have an odd-perfect matching (no need to have an edge incident to $v$ by definition of odd-perfect matching). For example, we can consider a path with 5 vertices with start $v=v_1$. If we remove the edge $v_1 v_2$, then remaining graph is an odd-perfect matching (i.e. $mp(G)\not \leq \delta(G)$). I think in this case, we need to take $F$ the set of all edges incident with vertex $v$ or $w$, where $w$ is a vertex with $\delta(G)\leq \deg (w)$ and $\deg(w)\leq$  any other degrees. Then $mp(G)\leq \delta(G)+deg(w)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of taking $F$ to be the edges incident with $v$ is correct.
Since $v$ has no edges incident with it in $G-F$, finding an odd perfect matching in $G-F$ is equivalent to finding a perfect matching in $G-v$ (since you must have $v$ as your unmatched vertex).
But this is not possible, since $G-v$ has an odd number of vertices.

[image]

EDIT: Another way of thinking about it that may be easier is just that a graph with $n$ even never has an odd perfect matching, by much the same parity argument that shows a graph with odd $n$ never has a perfect matching.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I agree that $G-v$ has no a perfect matching (because of your reason), but what about an odd-perfect matching? we have to show $G-v$ has no perfect and odd-perfect matching.

Comment: Is the preclusion number of a graph dependence of being odd or even of $n$ as well as the definition of perfect or odd-perfect matching? I mean, if $n$ is even, then in the question above, we suffice to show that $G-F$ has no perfect matching? Don't we need to show that $G-F$ has no odd-perfect matching?

Comment: @M.Ramana If $G-v$ has an odd perfect matching, that doesn't mean anything for $G-F$, since then $G-F$ has TWO unmatched vertices ($v$ and whatever is left out of the odd perfect matching of $G-v$). As for your second question: Yes, if $n$ is even, it suffices to show $G-F$ has no perfect matching, since $G-F$ can *never* have an odd perfect matching (no graph with even order can have an odd perfect matching). 

Similarly, when checking the preclusion number of an odd order graph, you don't need to check that $G-F$ has no perfect matching, because it *never* can just by its vertex count.

Comment: Why is finding an odd perfect matching in $G−F$ is equivalent to finding a perfect matching in $G−v$? In the definition, we say $F$ is a preclusion set if $G-F$ has no perfect matching (or odd-perfect matching). Where do we know $|F|$ is odd or even from to determine we need to show $G-F$ has no perfect matching or odd-perfect matching?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understood that no graph with even order can have an odd perfect matching. But if $n$ is even, how do you know $G-F$ also has even number of vertices?

Comment: $F$ is a set of edges, so $G-F$ and $G$ both have the same number of vertices (but a different number of edges). So if $G$ has even order, so does $G-F$.

Comment: That's right. I'm very sorry. It goes back to my low information about the graph theory. Thank you so much.

Comment: No need to apologise, the more you work with it the more stuff will make sense ^^

Comment: It sure does. You've got a point there. Thank you.

Comment: I'm so sorry again. In my question, $n$ is even. So we have to show that $G−F$ has no perfect matching. But in your answer, you said "finding an odd perfect matching in $G−F$ is equivalent to finding a perfect matching in $G−v$". But we need to say  finding an perfect matching in $G−F$ is equivalent to finding a old perfect matching in $G−v$ which is not a contradiction because $G-v$  has an odd number of vertices.

Comment: I think $G-F$ doesn't normally have perfect matching because there is no edge in $G-F$ which incident with $v$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the second part is correct. No edge can be incident with $v$.

Comment: But what is being even $n$ for? Can we say that the statement in the question is true when $n$ is also odd? I mean can we say for any $n$, $mp(G)\leq \delta(G)$?

Comment: I don't think this is true for odd $n$, because you can still have an odd perfect matching even if one vertex has no edges touching it. For example, I think you need to remove more than 4 edges from $K_5$ to preclude an odd perfect matching.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I put my answer below. I was wondering if you could check it to be true or not. Thank you.